# Why does the Befunge code 9332682811>\#+:#*9-#\_$.@ output 52256370?

Tags: befunge

Today I tried to make an account on [Esolangs.org](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Main_Page), the [esoteric programming languages](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Esoteric_programming_language) wiki. I'd contributed to a few wikis before, and I had one or two minor page edits I wanted to contribute.

...that is, until I saw the CAPTCHA verification puzzle used to create a new account.

[image: Captcha puzzle for Esolangs.org]

Using an obscure language for the CAPTCHA was most likely intended as a silly in-joke. However, I spent nearly half an hour trying to understand the language so I could create a new account.

Eventually I gave up and used an [online Befunge interpreter](https://www.bedroomlan.org/tools/befunge-playground#prog=hello,mode=run), which gave me the answer `52256370`.

**What I don't understand is *why* the output of `9332682811>\#+:#*9-#\_$.@` is `52256370`.**

I've seen a few comments suggesting it's a conversion from base-10 to base-9. However, when I tried to verify by converting `9332682811` with an [online base converter](http://www.unitconversion.org/numbers/base-10-to-base-9-conversion.html), I got a result of `26072072027`.

Comment: It's just a simple loop and some arithmetic. Perl translation created from https://esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge#Instructions: http://ideone.com/40CLcK

Comment: This is a base 9 converter.

Comment: It converts *from* base 9, the `9` isn't part of the number, and you put the input in backward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This program parses `332682811` as a little-endian base-9 integer and prints it in base-10.

Befunge interprets instructions on a 2D grid (or torus, depending on version), with an instruction pointer that can move freely in two dimensions. This program is a one-liner, so the instruction pointer only moves forward and backward.

`9332682811` pushes those digits individually onto Befunge's value stack, and then the following instructions perform a simple loop. In a normal iteration of the loop, things look like this:

```
Instructions              Meaning                                       Top stack values

9332682811>\#+:#*9-#\_$.@
          >               Set the instruction pointer to travel         a b
                          to the right.
           \              Swap the top 2 values on the stack.           b a
            #+            Nothing, since # means                        b a
                          skip the next instruction.
              :           Duplicate the top value on the stack.         b a a
                 9        Push 9.                                       b a a 9
                  -       Pop two values and push their difference.     b a (a-9)
                     _    Pop the top value and set the instruction     b a
                          pointer traveling right if the value is 0
                          or left otherwise.
                    \     Swap the top 2 values.                        a b
                 9        Push 9.                                       a b 9
                *         Pop two values and push their product.        a (b*9)
             +            Pop two values and push their sum.            (b*9 + a)
          >               Set the instruction pointer traveling
                          right again.
```

So unless the second value on the stack at the start of an iteration is 9, the iteration pops two values `b` and `a` and pushes `b*9 + a`.

If the second value *is* 9, the loop terminates and prints the top value:

```
Instructions              Meaning                                       Top stack values

9332682811>\#+:#*9-#\_$.@
                     _    Pop the top value and set the instruction     b a
                          pointer traveling right if the value is 0
                          or left otherwise.
                      $   Discard the top value.                        b
                       .  Pop and print the top value.
                        @
```

So, in summary, the program pushes a bunch of digits and repeatedly replaces `a` and `b` with `b*9+a` until it hits 9, the signal to stop. This is a base 9 converter.

If you try to verify this with [another base converter](http://ideone.com/XApDFM), make sure you get the endianness right. `332682811` is little-endian, so you may need to reverse it.